# Pipe audio through headphones and mic jack

Tags: audio, bluetooth, microphone

I have a Bluetooth headset and I'd like to pipe the microphone of the headset to the speaker(the port) of my laptop. And I would like to take the microphone input on my laptop and pipe it to my Bluetooth headphones.

Comment: Pulseaudio, or ALSA only?

Comment: @dirkt Ye I can use Pulseaudio, anything to get this setup working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Pulseaudio, use `module-loopback`. First get the names of the sources and sinks:

```
pacmd list-sources | grep name:
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

The create a loopback connection with

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback source="..." sink="..."
```

with the names of the source and sink you want, without the angular brackets.